# Embed WMV/MP4 using iFrame tag

Tags: html, iframe, video-embedding

Can a WMV or a MP4 file be embedded using an iFrame tag instead of an object tag?

No reason why I can't use an object, just wondering out of interest, I can only find examples using the object tag.

Example of the object tag:

```
<object id="MediaPlayer" width="600" height="500" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
        standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
        <param name="FileName" value="https://archive.org/download/Low5MBwmvfile/Low5MB.wmv" />
        <param name="ShowControls" value="true">
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
        <param name="autostart" value="false">
        <embed  type="application/x-mplayer2" src="https://archive.org/download/Low5MBwmvfile/Low5MB.wmv" align="middle" width="600" height="500" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0" name="MediaPlayer" />
</object>
```

I'm wondering can I do this with an iFrame?

```
<iframe src="https://archive.org/download/Low5MBwmvfile/Low5MB.wmv" width="600" height="500" ... />
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Was writing a different question earlier but found the answer while writing it up, changed the content forgot about the title, sorry about that

Comment: Thanks for the help Rene, hope above example makes it clearer